# Eigenvalues of matrices of order $p+q$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to find eigenvalues of following symmetric matrices?
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \;(p \; \text{times}) & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \;(q \; \text{times})\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \;(p \; \text{times}) & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \;(q \; \text{times})\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \;(p \; \text{times}) & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \;(q \; \text{times})\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\;(p \; \text{times}) & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\;(q \; \text{times}) \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\;(p \; \text{times}) & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\;(q \; \text{times}) \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\;(p \; \text{times}) & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\;(q \; \text{times}) \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\;(p \; \text{times}) & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\;(q \; \text{times}) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\;(p \; \text{times}) & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\;(q \; \text{times}) \\
\end{bmatrix}_{p+q}$$

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \;(p \; \text{times}) & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \;(q \; \text{times})\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \;(p \; \text{times}) & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \;(q \; \text{times})\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \;(p \; \text{times}) & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \;(q \; \text{times})\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\;(p \; \text{times}) & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\;(q \; \text{times}) \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\;(p \; \text{times}) & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\;(q \; \text{times}) \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\;(p \; \text{times}) & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\;(q \; \text{times}) \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\;(p \; \text{times}) & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\;(q \; \text{times}) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\;(p \; \text{times}) & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\;(q \; \text{times}) \\
\end{bmatrix}_{p+q}$$

I have tried the following,please verify my solution and guide me to solve it further

The charcteristic equation of $A$ is $det(A-xI)$=0

$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
1-x & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0  & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
0 & -x & 0 & \cdots & 0  & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -x & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -x & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & -x & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & -x & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & 0 & -x & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -x \\
\end{bmatrix}_{p+q}=0$

Taking $R_i\left(\dfrac{-1}{x}\right),i=p+1,p+2,\cdots,q$

$\Rightarrow \left(-x \right)^q\begin{bmatrix}
1-x & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0  & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
0 & -x & 0 & \cdots & 0  & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -x & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -x & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\[5mm]
\dfrac{-1}{x} & 
\dfrac{-1}{x} & 
\dfrac{-1}{x} & \cdots & 
\dfrac{-1}{x} & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\[5mm]
\dfrac{-1}{x} & \dfrac{-1}{x} & \dfrac{-1}{x} & \cdots & \dfrac{-1}{x} & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\[5mm]
\dfrac{-1}{x} & \dfrac{-1}{x} & \dfrac{-1}{x} & \cdots & \dfrac{-1}{x} & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\[5mm]
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\[5mm]
\dfrac{-1}{x} & \dfrac{-1}{x} & \dfrac{-1}{x} & \cdots & \dfrac{-1}{x} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}_{p+q}=0$

Taking $R_1-R_i,R_2-R_i,R_3-R_i,\cdots,R_p-R_i,i=1,2,3,\cdots,q$

$\Rightarrow \left(-x \right)^q\begin{bmatrix}
1-x+\dfrac{q}{x} & \dfrac{q}{x} & \dfrac{q}{x} & \cdots &    \dfrac{q}{x}  & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\[5mm]
\dfrac{q}{x} & -x+\dfrac{q}{x} & \dfrac{q}{x} & \cdots & \dfrac{q}{x}  & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\[5mm]
\dfrac{q}{x} & \dfrac{q}{x} & -x+\dfrac{q}{x} & \cdots &\dfrac{q}{x} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\dfrac{q}{x} & \dfrac{q}{x} & \dfrac{q}{x} & \cdots & -x+\dfrac{q}{x} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\[5mm]
\dfrac{-1}{x} & 
\dfrac{-1}{x} & 
\dfrac{-1}{x} & \cdots & 
\dfrac{-1}{x} & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\[5mm]
\dfrac{-1}{x} & \dfrac{-1}{x} & \dfrac{-1}{x} & \cdots & \dfrac{-1}{x} & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\[5mm]
\dfrac{-1}{x} & \dfrac{-1}{x} & \dfrac{-1}{x} & \cdots & \dfrac{-1}{x} & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\[5mm]
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\[5mm]
\dfrac{-1}{x} & \dfrac{-1}{x} & \dfrac{-1}{x} & \cdots & \dfrac{-1}{x} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}_{p+q}=0$

As the right block is zero matrix we have

$\Rightarrow \left(-x\right)^q \begin{bmatrix} 1-x+\dfrac{q}{x} & \dfrac{q}{x} & \dfrac{q}{x} & \cdots & \dfrac{q}{x}\\[5mm]
\dfrac{q}{x} & -x+\dfrac{q}{x} & \dfrac{q}{x} & \cdots & \dfrac{q}{x}\\[5mm]
\dfrac{q}{x} & \dfrac{q}{x} & -x+\dfrac{q}{x} & \cdots & \dfrac{q}{x}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\dfrac{q}{x} & \dfrac{q}{x} & -x+\dfrac{q}{x} & \cdots & \dfrac{q}{x}\\
\end{bmatrix}_p=0$

How to solve further?

Comment: thank you for  your observation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ has only $3$ distinct columns, $p+q-3$ of the eigenvalues of $A$ are zero.

We can reduce the problem of finding the non-zero eigenvalues of the $(p+q) \times (p+q)$ matrix $A$ down to the problem of finding the eigenvalues of a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

The columns of the matrix $$U = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{(p-1)}} & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\  0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{(p-1)}} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{q}} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{q}} \end{bmatrix}$$ are orthonormal, and have the same span as the columns of $A$.

Then, since $A$ is symmetric, we can write $A = U\widetilde{A}U^T$ where

$$\widetilde{A} := U^TAU = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & \sqrt{q} \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt{(p-1)q} \\ \sqrt{q} & \sqrt{(p-1)q} & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

If $v$ is an eigenvector of $\widetilde{A}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda \neq 0$, then the vector $x = Uv$ satisfies $Ax = U\widetilde{A}U^TUv = U\widetilde{A}v = \lambda Uv = \lambda x$, i.e. $x = Uv$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

So, the $3$ non-zero eigenvalues of $A$ are the eigenvalues of the $3 \times 3$ matrix $\widetilde{A}$. The characteristic polynomial for $\widetilde{A}$ is $$P_{\widetilde{A}}(\lambda) = \lambda^3 - \lambda^2 - pq\lambda + (p-1)q.$$ The roots of this polynomial don't have a nice closed form for general values of $p$ and $q$.

Similarly the matrix $B$ has only $3$ non-zero eigenvalues, which are the same as the eigenvalues of the matrix $$\widetilde{B} := U^TBU = \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & \sqrt{q} \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt{(p-1)q} \\ \sqrt{q} & \sqrt{(p-1)q} & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$ The characteristic polynomial for $\widetilde{B}$ is $$P_{\widetilde{B}}(\lambda) = \lambda^3 + \lambda^2 - pq\lambda - (p-1)q.$$ The roots of this polynomial also don't have a nice closed form for general values of $p$ and $q$.